# creating objects in PostgreSQL and Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm trying to create rows inside my PostgreSQL using scraped data from a website.

I'm pretty sure my approach is wrong.

here is tasks.py inside one of my Django apps which is supposed to do the scraping and then add the scraped data to db:

```
from models import Movies
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'any url'

r =  requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')

title = soup.find('a', class_='movie_name')
year = soup.find('span', class_='year')
rating = soup.find('p', class_='rate')

Movies.objects.create(
title = 'the movie name',
year = 2020,
rating = 8.7)
```

and this is my models.py :

```
class Movies(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    year = models.IntegerField(max_length=4)
    rating = models.FloatField(max_length=10)
```

What's the best way to scrape data and add it automatically to the database?

Update : I'm facing the error below :

```
    django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting 
    INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. 
You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE 
`enter code here`or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Comment: Are you experiencing any error ? If so which ?

Comment: @AlexTorx Yes I included the error

Comment: Have you configured the `DATABASES` variable in the `settings.py`file ?

Comment: Yes, and everything else works fine, I've created tables and added data to them in my other apps. but when I try to run the tasks.py I get this error

Comment: How do you call this code? You can't just run `python tasks.py`. You have to call it from view or using django-admin command https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-management-commands/ or any other way where django and settings is loaded

Comment: Oh! I didn't know that. Thanks, so I should write a function inside of django-admin that scrapes and adds to the db?

Comment: You can create function in `tasks.py` and just call it form custom django-admin command.

Answer (score 0):

If you still use Django you could easily use Djangos integration for PostGreSQL and just create new objects with `Movies.init(title, year, rating)`
If you just want to use a standalone PostGreSQL database you should Look into normal SQL.
I am not sure if this is what you wanted as an answer, but I am not sure what you wanted to know about the best way to scrape data and add it to the db.
It seems like you already found your data and know how to insert it into the db

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your code, the problem you are facing is that when you call your `task.py` code (namely with `python task.py`) you reference django stuff, while the django app was not loaded.

To solve this, you should place the code of your `task.py` file inside your `Movie` model like that :

```py
class Movies(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    year = models.IntegerField(max_length=4)
    rating = models.FloatField(max_length=10)

    @classmethod
    def scrap_movie(url):
        
        r =  requests.get(url).text

        soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')

        title = soup.find('a', class_='movie_name')
        year = soup.find('span', class_='year')
        rating = soup.find('p', class_='rate')

        return cls.objects.create(
            title=title,
            year=year,
            rating=rating,
        )
```

Then you can run this code from the django-admin command, or create a script that will use this function or any pattern that matches your requirements as long as it is executed in the scope of a django app. This way of doing actually makes use of Object Oriented Programming, is more Pythonic and Django-oriented (at least in my opinion).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but how should I correctly call the function you defined in models?

Comment: Well, if you have a web interface associated to your project, you could create a form with a field expecting the url of the movie to scrap and add to database and there could be a button performing a `POST` of the URL to an endpoint that would call the method I proposed you.